# Infinite loop with getters and setters in class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
alert("Hello")

class Dog {

  constructor(name, weight)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.weight = weight;
  }

  /*
  get name(){
    return this.name;
  }

  set name(value){
    this.name = value;
  }
  */
}

alert("Hello1");

let pies = new Dog("Reksio", 999);

alert("Hello2");
alert(pies.name);
```

This code works perfect without getter and setter. However, after uncommenting sections with them, it crashes oddly:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):44)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
    at Dog.set name [as name] ((index):45)
```

1. Why can't I use getter alone?
2. Why does it crash as if there was an infinite recursion after adding simple getter and setter?
3. How to fix getter and setter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By having the setter `name` set the member variable `name`, you are calling the setter `name` again and again until you overflow the stack.

Directly addressing your comment:

> I Thought that the setter is engaged only for external calls

There isn't really a notion of "internal" or "external" calls.  I suppose you define "internal" as "from within a member function" or in a place where `this` is the constructed Object.  Either way, that isn't the case. After you have defined a setter, any time you attempt to set the property, whether you are doing it "internally" or "externally", the setter will be called.

You'll have to use an intermediate variable like `_name`.  Otherwise you will infinitely recurse into setting `name`.

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name = "") {
    this._name = name;
  }
  set name(newVal) {
    this._name = newVal;
  }
  get name() {
    return this._name;
  }
}

const f = new Foo("foo");
console.log(f.name);
```

If you want to privatize the internal `_name` member variable so that an API consumer is forced to go through `name`, I have had luck using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object that keeps a static reference of all instances of `Foo`s to an Object of "private" variables.  It's likely not very efficient, but if privacy is more important than performance, it's an option.

Comment: I Thought that the setter is engaged only for external calls. Strange JS logic struck again ;)

Comment: @0x6B6F77616C74 Accessing a property is just accessing a property. There is no concept of internal/external.